# Azure SQL Database V12 Change Collation

Tags: azure-sql-database

I've tried to alter data collation for a Azure SQL DB V12 database with this command:

```
ALTER DATABASE aguia COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI
```

And receive the follow message:

> The database could not be exclusively locked to perform the operation.

If I try to run this command, in order to lock exclusively:

```
ALTER DATABASE aguia SET SINGLE_USER
```

I receive this message:

> The operation cannot be performed on database "aguia" because it is
>   involved in a database mirroring session or an availability group.
>   Some operations are not allowed on a database that is participating in
>   a database mirroring session or in an availability group.

How can I get around?

Regards, JP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are in master database and run below query.further you also can see which sessions are accessing your database by below dmv.

```
ALTER DATABASE aguia COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI

select * from sys.sysprocesses where dbid=db_id('your db name')
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. But, even now that database is accent insensitive, my queries with "like" statement stay sensitive about accents.

Comment: can you try querying sys.databases to see if the collation changed? Also it would be great if you can paste the queries you are running

Comment: Quering sys.databeses, I can see that my database is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI. But, this query doesn't behave as AI:

select * from Pessoa where Nome like '%joao%'

Comment: Good new! I discovered that even after alter database collation, collums in tables remain in old collaion. I should change colums collation too. Regards!

Comment: As far as my understanding,Database collation will be default for all tables,but only if we specify table level collation,it over rides default collation of database,